# Checking whether it's indeed a key -> value pair that I inserted

Tags: perl

I am trying to debug an issue *(not my source entirely)*.

I have a package I made which is a wrapper for `IO::Socket` to create socket.

```
package mysock::my_sock;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Scalar::Util 'refaddr';
use IO::Socket;
use IO::Select;

my %socket;
my $dbg_flag = 0;
our ($obj,$sel,$eol);

sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my $args = shift;
   my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET(%{$args});
   my $obj = bless \do {my $anon_scalar}, class;   # <-- Added.
   if (!$sock) { warn "Cannot create socket: $!/$@\n" if ($dbg_flag); 
      return undef; 
   }
   my $sel = new IO::Select($sock);
   if(!sel){ warn "Could not create select obj: $!/$@\n" if ($dbg_flag); 
      return undef; 
   }

   # Initialize some vars for class
   $socket{ refaddr $obj }->{_SOCKET_} = $sock;
   $socket{ refaddr $obj }->{_SELECT_} = $sel;
   $socket{ refaddr $obj }->{_EOL_}    = $eol;
   $socket{ refaddr $obj }->{_BUFFER_} = {};

   return $obj;
  }

 1;
```

Now when I call/use my package in my script this way everything **works fine** :

```
use warnings;
use mysock::my_sock;
sub new {
          my $var = mysock::my_sock->new({
                                    ip    => '10.109.157.249',  # Hard coded IP
                                    port  => '2002',            # Hard coded port
                                    reuse => 1,
                                    eol   =>''
                                   }) or die "unable to connect $!\n";
           return var;
        }  # This sub will go to another package, putting it here for brevity.

my $box = new();
```

The above code is straight forward. I have created a socket handle successfully. **No** problems so far.

But when I modify my new function this way in my script so that i could pass the ip and port, i can't get it to work no matter what i do:

```
sub new {
    my ($ip_, $port_) = @_;
    my @AoH = (
                 {
                    reuse => 1,
                    eol =>''
                  }
              );
    $AoH[0]{ip} = $ip_ ;               #insert key => value to my AoH
    $AoH[0]{port} = $port_ ;           #insert key => value to my AoH
    my $var = mysock::my_sock->new($AoH[0]) or die "unable to connect- $!\n";
    return $var;
  }

 my $box = new('10.150.180.245','2011');   # pass ip/port as args.
```

I tried passing `my $var = mysock::my_sock->new($AoH)` or `my $var = mysock::my_sock->new($AoH)` and even `my $var = mysock::my_sock->new(\@AoH)`. None of these works.

When I dump the `$args` that I get inside my package, for both cases it prints a hash:

```
$VAR1 = {
           "reuse" => 1,
           "ip" => "10.63.122.49",
           "port" => 6002,
           "eol" => ""
         };
```

I am using perl debugger, and it shows the same hash above when i run my script either way, which is what confuses me. If they are the same, then why won't the second method work?

Could the hash somehow gotten over written? I dunno what's gone wrong. `$sock` in my package doesn't get the socket, and I couldn't get `IO::Socket` to bless me w/ a socket call when i use my modified function where i pass the params so i return `undef`.

Can you help?

Comment: You have a typo in your first code block that makes it impossible to compile. Please don't retype code here, but rather copy/paste your real code.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You are passing the first element of the array. That's your has reference. You put that into `$args` in your `new` method. Then you dereference it into a list when you create your IO::Socket object. That all looks fine. The way you put the IP and port into that hashref is fine, though cumbersome. You could just do `{ reuse => 1, eol => q{}, port => $port, ip => $ip }`. But it doesn't make a difference really.

Comment: "I can't get it to work" and "it won't work" aren't problem descriptions. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Why are you using `refaddr $obj` in your code?  And why have you not defined `$obj` before using it?  All future `->new()` calls will just map to `refaddr $obj` which will return `undef`.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed those bugs. I typed it in, instead of copy/paste at the time of posting.

Comment: OK, but xxfelixxx's comment still applies: `refaddr $obj` will be `undef` every time. And this is still not a [mcve].

Comment: ok. sorry, I missed creating the `$obj`. I checked the source this morning and added the missing parts.

Comment: hi @xxfelixxx , i have updated my question with the changes, can you kindly check now?

Comment: `!sel` should be `!$sel` to satisfy the compilation requirement...`class` should be `$class` in your `bless` line...

Comment: Please, if you are going to post some code on SO, try copying it and saving it and seeing if it compiles...because no on wants to deal with non-compiling code, it just slows everything down and makes people less eager to help.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the compilation issues...what your code needs are some accessors, since the object you return from `->new()` is just an bare object reference.

For example, you could add the following accessor inside **mysock::my_sock.pm**

```
sub socket {
    my ($obj) = @_;
    return $socket{ refaddr $obj }->{_SOCKET_};
}
```

And then from a script, you could see the different objects:

```
my $box1 = new('10.150.180.245','2011');   # pass ip/port as args.
my $box2 = new('10.150.180.246','2012');   # pass ip/port as args.
print "Box1 Socket: " . $box1->socket() . "\n";
print "Box2 Socket: " . $box2->socket() . "\n";
```

Which outputs (on my machine, your memory addresses will vary):

```
Box1 Socket: IO::Socket::INET=GLOB(0x5567efa4eb68)
Box2 Socket: IO::Socket::INET=GLOB(0x5567efa64f98)
```

Another thing is that it is not necessary to use `refaddr`, as you can just store/retrieve hash references directly inside other hashes, i.e.

```
# instead of 
$socket{ refaddr $obj }->{ some_field } = 2;
my $some_field = $socket{ refaddr $obj }->{ some_field };

# you can just
$socket{ $obj }->{ some_field } = 2;
my $some_field = $socket{ $obj }->{ some_field };
```